# not able to connect to phpmyadin

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

The  apache server stopped and lamp is started.
The terminal shows lamp server is working fine but not able to enter phpmyadmin

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the already installed MySQL server.

- stop lampp
- stop the MySQL server by one of these commands:

  - `sudo service mysql stop`
  - `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
- start lampp again